CSS Animations not working after a a Gatsby Built
My CSS animations are not working after a build.
Gatsby is building the wrong CSS bundle
The original CSS is:
@supports (animation-timeline: view()) {
  #hero-slide-scroll {
    min-height: 90dvh;
    height: 90dvh;
  }

  .scroll-slide {
    animation: scroll-slide linear forwards;
    animation-timeline: view();
    animation-range-start: 100dvh;

  }

}


The complied CSS becomes:
@supports (animation-timeline: view()) {
  #hero-slide-scroll {
    min-height: 90dvh;
    height: 90dvh;
  }

  .scroll-slide {
    
    animation-timeline: view();
    animation-range-start: 100dvh;
    animation: scroll-slide linear forwards;

  }

}


Do you know how to fix this issue?
